# Facebook test users with phone number instead of email

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-test-users

I've been trying to create a bunch of test users for my test application that will be mocking a case when user signed up to Facebook using his phone number (not his email).

Turns out that the tool to create test users (`App -> roles -> test users`) allows to create only users who have email and there's no way (AFAIK) to change the data without logging in to Facebook as this user and changing his account settings.

Is it not possible or am I missing something?

**EDIT 1:**
I'm not actually able to add a phone number without verification

Comment: You are correct. There is no way to create a test user without email

Comment: so what you did? how you handled it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to add testers with their phones. You can add your testers by their fbids or usernames.

[image: Facebook developers reference]

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this option before.

Comment: Dam, there are some Facebook accounts that have no email address (Phone only). It breaks a lotta logins.

Comment: At this moment, to accept the Tester invitation, they require you to register as a Facebook Developer, which in turn requires an email address! So this doesn't work anymore or I'm missing something :(

Answer (score 3):

As others say there is no way to have test user without email address.

What you can do however is to create test user and when logging into your app deny access to email. It will have nearly same effect as logging in with user that has phone number instead of email. You can do it in edit section while logging in(as shown in pictures)
[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]